# Why does the Azure Virtual Network Express Route Gateway require public IP?

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-virtual-network

I need to setup connection between Express Route and VNET in Azure.

It requires to create Virtual Network Gateway as Express Route Gateway type.
This Gateway ask for public IP.
So, I wonder why we need the public IP? Can Vnet and Express route can interact through private IP?
Please help me answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [Microsoft FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-faqs#why-is-there-a-public-ip-address-associated-with-the-expressroute-gateway-on-a-virtual-network):

> The public IP address is used for internal management only, and
> doesn't constitute a security exposure of your virtual network.

Answer (score 1):

Vpn gateway is used to send the encrypted traffic across the public internet for this communication it requires a public IP. The public IP assigned to the virtual network gateway will let you connect Azure VPN gateway from your on-premises network or the Internet.

When you create a virtual network gateway, you need to specify several settings. One of the required settings, '-GatewayType', specifies whether the gateway is used for ExpressRoute, or VPN traffic. The two gateway types are:

**Vpn** -  you use the gateway type 'Vpn'. to setup Site-to-Site, Point-to-Site, and VNet-to-VNet connections all use a VPN gateway.

**ExpressRoute** - To send network traffic on a private connection, you use the gateway type 'ExpressRoute'. This is also referred to as an ExpressRoute gateway and is the type of gateway used when configuring ExpressRoute.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-about-virtual-network-gateways)